# Why is there a reboot.target?

Tags: linux

In Linux there are different systemd targets for different states of the system.
For example, graphical.target for a GUI.

**I don't understand why reboot.target exists.**

Why not just use the reboot command/service? **Why is reboot a target?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the system uses "systemctl" for process control, and /sbin/reboot (on my OSes) is simply a symlink to /bin/systemctl.

So the "reboot" command uses the "reboot.target" to do its work.